# Prove the sum and product of real numbers are continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, binary-operations

To start with, let us study the continuity of the sum of real numbers.

Precisely speaking, let us consider the function $f:\textbf{R}^{2}\to\textbf{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = x + y$.

We want to prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{|x - a|^{2} + |y - b|^{2}} < \delta \Rightarrow |x + y - a - b| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Since $|x - a| \leq \sqrt{|x - a|^{2} + |y - b|^{2}}$ as well as $|y - b| \leq \sqrt{|x - a|^{2} + |y - b|^{2}}$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $\delta = \varepsilon/2 > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{|x - a|^{2} + |y - b|^{2}} < \delta \Rightarrow |x + y - a - b| \leq |x-a| + |y-b| < 2\delta = \varepsilon
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Let us now try to prove the continuity of the product.

Precisely speaking, let us consider the function $f:\textbf{R}^{2}\to\textbf{R}$ such that $f(x,y) = xy$.

We want to prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{|x - a|^{2} + |y - b|^{2}} < \delta \Rightarrow |xy - ab| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

I do not know how to proceed, but I tried to approach it as follows:
\begin{align*}
|xy - ab| & = |xy - xb + xb - ab|\\\\
& = |x(y-b) + b(x-a)|\\\\
& \leq |x||y-b| + |b||x-a|\\\\
& \leq |x|\delta + |b|\delta
\end{align*}

Could someone finish it or propose another way to solve it?

**EDIT**

In accordance to the comment of @Noobmathematician, I have tried the following approach. Any comments are appreciated.

Let us suppose the sequence $(a_{n},b_{n})$ converges to $(a,b)$ in $\textbf{R}^{2}$. We shall prove that $f(a_{n},b_{n})$ converges to $f(a,b)$ in $\textbf{R}$. But a sequence converges in $\textbf{R}^{2}$ iff it converges coordinatewise. That is to say, $a_{n}\to a$ and $b_{n}\to b$.

Consequently, $a_{n}$ is bounded: $|a_{n}|\leq M$

Hence we have
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| & =|a_{n}b_{n} - a_{n}b + a_{n}b - ab|\\\\
& = |a_{n}(b_{n} - b) + b(a_{n} - a)|\\\\
& \leq |a_{n}||b_{n} - b| + |b||a_{n} - a|\\\\
& \leq M|b_{n} - b| + |b||a_{n} - a|
\end{align*}

Taking the limit from both sides and due to the squeeze theorem, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n}b_{n} - ab) = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}b_{n} = ab
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Comment: Your argument is correct. It remains to notice that we can assume that $\delta<1$ and  then $|x|<|a|+1$. Finally let $\delta=\frac{1}2(\frac{\epsilon}{|a|+1+|b|})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is right and precise .
But I would have used sequential criteria for continuity .
Trust me sequential criteria will help you in many tricky situations and avoiding $\epsilon-\delta$ mess.

$$(x_n,y_n) \to (a,b) \implies x_n \to a \text{ and }y_n\to b$$
Hence
$$(x_n+ y_n)\to( a+ b) \text{ and }(x_n\cdot y_n)\to (a\cdot b)$$

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to include your comments. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Yes it's correct .

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 2):

An other way.

You  begin by proving that 
If $ f $ is continuous, then $ f^2 $ is continuous (easy), then

use the identity

$$xy = \frac{(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2}{4}$$
to prove that
$$(x,y)\mapsto xy$$
is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!